# Prove that $3p^{n/2 - 2} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^n}{a_{i - 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2} \ge (\sum_{i = 1}^pa_i^2)^{n/2 - 1}$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Given $p$ positives $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{p - 1}, a_p \ (p \in \mathbb N, p \ge 3)$ and $n \ge 4$. Prove that $$\frac{a_1^n}{a_p^2 + a_pa_2 + a_2^2} + \frac{a_2^n}{a_1^2 + a_1a_3 + a_3^2} + \cdots + \frac{a_{p - 1}^n}{a_{p - 2}^2 + a_{p - 2}a_p + a_p^2} + \frac{a_p^n}{a_{p - 1}^2 + a_{p - 1}a_1 + a_1^2}$$ isn't lesser than $\dfrac{(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_{p - 1}^2 + a_p^2)^{n/2 - 1}}{3p^{n/2 - 2}}$.

(In other words, $$3p^{n/2 - 2} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^n}{a_{i - 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2} \ge \left(\sum_{i = 1}^pa_i^2\right)^{n/2 - 1},$$ where $a_0 = a_p$ and $a_{p + 1} = a_1$.)

Without loss of generalisation, assume that $a_k \ge a_l, \forall k, l$ such that $p \ge k \ge l \ge 1$.

Let $$P = \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^n}{a_{i - 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2}$$

and $$Q = \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^{n - 1}(a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1})}{a_{i - 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2}.$$

We have that $$P + Q = \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^{n - 1}(a_{i - 1} + a_i + a_{i + 1})}{a_{i - 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2} \ge \frac{2}{3} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^{n - 1}(a_{i - 1} + a_i + a_{i + 1})}{a_{i + 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}^2} \ (1)$$

According to Hölder's inequality, $$\sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_{i + 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}^2}{a_i(a_{i - 1} + a_i + a_{i + 1})} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^{n - 1}(a_{i - 1} + a_i + a_{i + 1})}{a_{i + 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}^2} \ge \left(\sum_{i = 1}^pa_i^2\right)^{n/2 - 1} \ (2)$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have that, $$\sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_{i + 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}^2}{a_i(a_{i - 1} + a_i + a_{i + 1})} \cdot (P + Q) \ge \frac{2}{3} \cdot \left(\sum_{i = 1}^pa_i^2\right)^{n/2 - 1}$$

We need to prove that $$\sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^{n - 1}(a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1})}{a_{i - 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2} \ge \frac{\displaystyle \left(\sum_{i = 1}^pa_i^2\right)^{n/2 - 1}}{3} \cdot \left[\frac{2}{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_{i + 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}^2}{a_i(a_{i - 1} + a_i + a_{i + 1})}} - \frac{1}{p^{n/2 - 2}}\right]$$

And this is where I am stuck. Of course, I had a few more ideas on my mind such as $$\sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^{n - 1}(a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1})}{a_{i - 1}^2 + a_{i - 1}a_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2}$$

$$ \le \frac{1}{3} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{a_i^{n - 1}(a_{i + 1} + a_{i - 1})}{a_{i + 1}a_{i - 1}} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^p\left[a_i^{n - 1} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{a_{i + 1}} + \frac{1}{a_{i - 1}}\right)\right],$$ and perhaps, through the rearrangement inequality, $$\sum_{i = 1}^p\left[a_i^{n - 1} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{a_{i + 1}} + \frac{1}{a_{i - 1}}\right)\right] \le 2 \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^pa^{n - 2}.$$

But that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you are making it out to be. First, do a C-S as follows:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^p\dfrac{a_i^n}{a_{i-1}^2+a_{i-1}a_{i+1}+a_{i+1}^2}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{a_{i-1}^2+a_{i-1}a_{i+1}+a_{i+1}^2}\right)\geq$$

$$\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^pa_i^{n/2}\right)^2 = p^2M(n/2)^{n}\quad (\dagger)$$
where we denote the power mean as for our numbers as:
$$M(k) = \left(\dfrac{a_1^k+a_2^k+\dots a_p^k}{p}\right)^{\frac 1k}.$$

But the second term on the LHS is bounded above by:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n({a_{i-1}^2+a_{i-1}a_{i+1}+a_{i+1}^2})\leq 3\sum_{i=1}^pa_i^2 = 3pM(2)^2.$$
Now denote our original expression as $A$ (the first term in the C-S), then we obtain:
$$A\geq\dfrac{p^2M(n/2)^{n}}{3pM(2)^2} = \dfrac{pM(n/2)^{n}}{3M(2)^2}.$$

Finally, the RHS of what we try to prove is simply:
$$\dfrac{(\sum_{i=1}^pa_i^2)^{n/2-1}}{3p^{n/2-2}} = \dfrac{p}{3}M(2)^{n-2}.$$

So our inequality now reduces to:
$$M(n/2)^{n}\geq M(2)^n$$
which is trivial since the power mean is a non-decreasing function of $k$ and $n/2\geq 2$ as given.

Comment: That's really clever, I should have thought of the power mean inequality beforehand. Thanks for that!

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt no problem. In my experience, $n$ variable symmetric, homogeneous inequalities usually simple like this or very difficult, as opposed to three or four variable inequalities.